# Как развернуть приложение на Qt на другой Windows машине?

Tags: windows, qt, c++

Как правильно проинсталировать на другом компьютере программу с ОС Windows, написанную на Qt C++? Проект в Qt Creator. Делаю релиз. Через запуск из Qt Creator проект запускается. Если через проводник зайти и открыть приложение в папке release, то возникает ошибка: отсутствует `QtCore4.dll`. Допустим, я `PATH` пропишу, на моем компьютере найдется, но клиенту же не скажешь, прописывайте ручками библиотеки. Вот интересует вопрос именно развертывания приложения под Windows.

Если есть статьи на эту тему, буду рад и такому ответу, с удовольствием почитаю.

Comment: Можно просто рядом класть нужные библиотеки.

Comment: @helpforprogrammer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

У вас есть два варианта:

1. Поставлять вместе с программой все необходимые dll'ки Qt. В первую очередь Windows ищет библиотеки в папке с программой, поэтому достаточно будет положить их туда. Вариант достаточно громоздкий - совсем недавно я написал небольшое приложение на Qt Widgets (размер exe'шника около 700 КБ), которое потянуло за собой 60 МБ Qt'шных библиотек.
2. Слинковать все необходимые библиотеки Qt с вашим приложением статически. То же приложение разрослось с 700 КБ до 10 МБ, однако сил и времени на статическую линковку ушло уйма (чего стоит только перекомпиляция Qt из исходников!).

Comment: А есть ли автоматизированные средства, которые сами проанализируют проект и добавят туда нужные библиотеки? Размер да, пусть будет большим, только не всю QT положит, а только нужные библиотеки.

Comment: @helpforprogrammer, 70 МБ - это был не весь Qt, просто виджеты за собой много чего тянут) Для определения списка библиотек я пользовался программой [Dependancy Walker|http://www.dependencywalker.com/].

Comment: Только что добавил 5 dll-ок, приложение заработало. Но это было все методом исключения, пока программа перестала просить библиотеки. Вопрос, есть ли другой способ сразу узнать называния нужных dll-ок и если программа запустилась, может возникнуть ситуация, что она попросит еще новые dll-ки в процессе выполнения?

Comment: dll они на то и dll, что подключаются во время выполнения. все зависит от вашей программы.

Comment: Скорее всего на нулевой машине попросит еще рантайм именно того компилятора, которым собирали.

Также не стоит забывать, в каком режиме собирается приложение - для qt дебаг требует одних длл, а релиз других, при этом первые больше чуть ли не в 10 раз за счет отладочной информации и называются обычно имя модуля + буква d, например, Qt5Core*`d`*.dll.

Comment: @helpforprogrammer:
Могу помочь Вам частично автоматизировать этот процесс. За небольшое "Спасибо" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Статьи [есть](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html). Там в конце есть раздел The Windows Deployment Tool. Я им никогда не пользовался, попробуйте возможно годная штука. Обычно все библиотеки просто складываю рядом с исполняемым файлом. И конечно [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) вам в помощь, хотя он не всё может определить.

Answer (score 1):

Я обращался с подобным вопросом к производителю. Ответ примерно такой:

1. Купить лицензионную версию, котороая позволяет необходимую информацию (подчёркиваю, что не всё содержимое библиотек, а только необходимую информацию) поместить в *.exe - файл.
   Мои предложения:
2. Свободно распространяемая версия Qt предполагает распространять и родных *.dll. Сделайте свой инсталятор и включите туда необходимые библиотеки (кстати, в сети такие уже есть).
3. На одном из форумов встречал советы, как "переделать" Qt, чтобы он включал в *.exe содержимое библиотек. Это возможно, но, во-первых, это нарушает лицензию, и к Вам производитель может предъявить иск, а во вторых, размер исполняемого файла в этом случае становится больше на размер используемых библиотек (вместо, допустим, 500 КБ будет "весить" 40-50 МБ).

Comment: С нарушением лицензии в пункте 3 не все так однозначно - насколько помню, условия LGPL, под которой qt распространяется, она позволяет переделать без нарушения, но надо открыть, что именно переделали. Поскольку вы все равно берете то, как собирается qt из интернета (т.е. оно уже открыто), пересборка ничего не нарушает вообще. При этом статическая линковка при LGPL вроде бы тоже не запрещена, да и выкладка сырцов реально означает не выложить их сразу куда-нибудь, а только то, что ты обязан их предоставить, в случае если у тебя их попросят, что реально не так уж часто и происходит.

Comment: Ну а представители производителя, естественно, пытаются склонить к покупке коммерческой версии, вот несколько и сгущают краски или же не очень афишируют возможность статической линковки. Кстати, не уверен, что размер исполняемого файла будет больше именно на размер библиотек, вроде бы таки только на размер того, что нужно из библиотек, но это мелочи.